# Xamarin HttpClient.GetAsync method returns Java.IO.IOException

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My project gets Java.IO.IOException on

```
await client.GetAsync(apiUrl)
```

If I don't use async method, its returns System.AggregateException.

```
client.GetAsync(apiUrl).Result
```

[image: exception]

Comment: That means that device can not reach your server, or device has no internet (make sure that test device has internet access and also try to ping your server ip )

Comment: Its reaches to api website on chrome. Also my application has this code on AssemblyInfo.cs file: [assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.Internet)]
Also in manifest file: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: could try to open api url from chrome on your test device ?

Comment: Its reaches but there is a problem with application permissions I guess. I'm trying to test internet connection on application.

Comment: I'm not sure but I guess this is Cleartext error. Becouse when I try to post something on another page, It returned as Cleartext HTTP traffic to 192.168.1.7 not permitted. On GetAsync, Its not giving this error explanation. I will configure the permission and post the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This error is apparently becouse of Cleartext Traffic Permission.
I added android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" attribute to application tag on AndroidManifest file and it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error was caused by updating the Xamarin.Essentials NuGet to a version later than 1.7.5.

I solved the problem by adding:

```
<intent>
   <action android:name="android.support.customtabs.action.CustomTabsService" />
</intent>
```

to my AndroidManifest.xml-file.